# Websecurity not working

Tags: visual-studio

I put this code in _AppStart.cshtml to make tables in the database (VS 2012)
The Problem is there is an error on WebSecurity  i.e The name WebSecurity does not exist in th 
current context

@using System.Web.Security;
@{

WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("MembershipExample","UserProfile","UserId","UserName", true);
}

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a reference to `System.Web` to your project (in the Project Manager on the right side, right-click `References` and choose `Add`).

You can then add a `using System.Web.Security` to your code file.